# Approximating partial series $\sum_{j=1}^{p} \sqrt{1-r^{2|k-j|}}/j$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, approximation

I'm working with the following series:

$$S_k = \sum_{j=1}^{p} \frac{\sqrt{1-r^{2|k-j|}}}{j} $$
here $|r|<1$, $k \leq p$.

Naturally, for small $r$ the series approaches harmonic sums $H_k \approx \gamma + \log(k) + 1/2k - 1/12k^2$, however, I'm trying to find a more manageable expression to work with..

By numerical experiments (guesswork mostly) I find that the following works reasonably well for $|r|<0.9$:

$$ S_k \approx H_p + \log\left(\frac{\beta_{11}}{1 + \exp\{\beta_{12} + \beta_{13} \cdot r\}}\right)\frac{1}{k} + e^{\beta_{21} + \beta_{22} r} \frac{1}{k^2} $$
for some numerical values $\beta_{11},\beta_{12},\beta_{13},\beta_{21},\beta_{22}$. Further, accuracy for $r$ closer to 1 can be improved by additional terms $k^{-3}$ and, probably, deeper expansion into $\text{exp}(\beta_{21} + \beta_{22} r + \beta_{23} r^2 + \ldots )$ near the $k^{-2}$ term.

All this suggests a possible expansion through $k^{-1}, k^{-2}, \ldots$, similar to approximation of $H_k$, just the summation weights will probably depend from $r$.

Does there exist any similar approximation that I could use analytically?

Comment: Very interesting problem ! $\to +1$. I am working on it.

Comment: Plot $r^{-2 n}\Phi \left(r^{-2 n},1,k+1\right)$ as a function of $r$ for some values of $n$ and $k$. It is very interesting (at least to me). Now, I have to go (dinner time here). Cheers :-)

Comment: I am still stuck. Take care : in title and text, the problem is not the same because of the story about $p$ (i did not give sufficient attention to this point). Could you clarify ?

Answer (score 1):

*Just a few preliminary ideas (for the time being, I hope)*

Using the expansion
$$\sqrt{1-r^{2|k-j|}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}r^{2n|k-j|}$$ Let
$$a_n=(-1)^n \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}r^{2n|k-j|}$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{a_n}j=(-1)^{n+1} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}  \left(r^{-2 n}\Phi \left(r^{-2 n},1,k+1\right)+r^{2
   k n} \log \left(1-r^{-2 n}\right)\right)$$ where appears  the Lerch transcendent function.

Difficult to give now more than for "small" values of $r$
$$r^{-2 n}\Phi \left(r^{-2 n},1,k+1\right)\sim -\frac 1 {k+1}$$

Now, the problem is to work

$$r^{2k n} \log \left(1-r^{-2 n}\right)$$ whish seems to be more problematic

*To follow, I hope and wish*

Comment: @Nutle. The problem is with the logarithm not with Larch. I must say that I am currently stuck. I need a break on this problem.

Comment: @Nutle. I agree but to prove it ? I am still stuck ! Cheers