# Proving that $\;\text{Im}\left[r\log\left(\frac{-1 + r}{r}\right)\right]= \pi r$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

> Assume $r \in (0,1)$, I want to prove that
>
> $$ \text{Im}\left[r\log\left(\frac{-1 + r}{r}\right)\right]=\pi r$$

This is probably something trivial, but I don't have much experience with complex numbers. Are there any known identities for similar expressions?

As a side note, this logarithm cancels out a specific imaginary part of a Lerch Transcendent in [another problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3978724/approximating-partial-series-sum-j-1p-sqrt1-r2k-j-j), so I can only guess that it's equal to $\pi i$.

Comment: What is the meaning $r$ in the both side ? Also $r=0$ is not possible

Comment: unless I am missing something, I do not think what you have written is true. Notice if you take e to the power of both sides you clearly get something different.

Comment: My bad, I will edit the question

Comment: @lonestudent corrected for $r$, it was probably redundant.

Comment: Are you familiar with the *complex* logarithm which is defined as $\log(z) = \log|z| + i \arg z$?

Comment: @Moosh I'm not sure if my question makes sense after correction, but I'm mainly interested in the imaginary part of the logarithm. But I should maybe repost this for evaluation instead of "proving"

Comment: I think it should be $\;r\in(0,1)\;$ , as in the extreme points of the unit interval the expression isn't defined

Comment: @DonAntonio you're right, thanks a lot!

Comment: Still not quite right -- $(0,1)$ not $(0,1]$, because at $r = 1$ we have $\dfrac {r-1} r= 0$ and logarithm of $0$ is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be that by $\;log\;$ you meant the complex log, something which isn't given...and thus:

$$\log\frac{-1+r}r=\ln\left|\frac{-1+r}r\right|+i\arg\frac{-1+r}r$$

Now, assuming the usual main branch of the complex logarithm, $\;-\pi<\arg\le\pi\;$ , we get that

$$0<r< 1\implies\frac{-1+r}r<0\implies \arg\frac{-1+r}r=\pi\implies\text{Im}\left(\log\frac{-1+r}r\right)=\pi$$

and multiplying by $\;r\;$ gives you the result.

Observe though that the imaginary part of the logarithm is $\;\pi\;$ ...without the $\;i\;$ . Both the real and imaginary parts of a complex number are *real*

Comment: Why is it necessary to multiply by $r$? You have already obtained the result of the original poster.

Comment: @Angelo That's what was written in the original question. You can check in the edited part.

Comment: I cannot see the original question. What was written in it?

Comment: @Angelo To the left of the OP's name there's written "edited". If you click there you can see all the versions opf the edited part (in this case, a question). The very first version was to prove that  $$r\log\frac{-1+r}r=\pi i$$ which, of course, was wrong as it should have been what is written now: the imaginary part...etc.

Comment: Now, I have just fixed it. Thank you for your clarification.